# replacing all values smaller than top n (different) largest pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]})
```

I want to replace all values that are smaller than the top three different values with `1`.

Afterwards it shoould look like this:

```
"A"
1 
4 
4
4
4
1
1
1
1
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
```

I tried using `.value_counts()` and `.nlargest()`. The latter counts same values multiple times, which is not what I need.

Comment: e.g. `df['A'] = np.where(df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('size') < 3, 1, df['A'])`

Comment: "replace all values that are smaller than the top three different values".. aren't the largest three different values `9`, `8` and `7`? So you'd have to replace `4` and leave `7` in, or am I missing something?